# What is truthy or falsy in Mustache and Handlebars?

Tags: mustache, handlebars.js

In JavaScript:

```
falsy: false, null, undefined, 0, -0, NaN, ""
truthy: everything else, including  [] and {}  (empty array and empty object)
```

But in Handlebars, it seems like it is (from [Handlebars's docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/)) for `{{#if foo}}`:

```
falsy: false, undefined, null, "", []
truthy: everything else, including 0, -0, {}
```

`undefined` and `NaN` cannot be listed as a value in a JSON file, so I can't test it using a Java Mustache renderer, although, if I don't define a property at all, then it is probably just `undefined` and it is taken as falsy.

The above is for `{{#if foo}}`, and to make things more complicated, what about just `{{#foo}}` in Handlebars and in Mustache?  Are the truthy and falsy rules exactly the same as `{{#if foo}}`?  If possible, please provide pointers to docs to support your claim.  Hopefully, implementation of Mustache or Handlebars in PHP or Java or other languages follow the exact same rules.

I also found that for [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html), it seems `{{#foo}}` is called a section, and its rule is:

```
falsy: whatever falsy in JavaScript, plus []
truthy: everything else
```

But it seems that can.js's implementation of Mustache/Handlebars treats `0` as falsy. (See http://jsfiddle.net/kAt7E/45/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/kAt7E/46/ or http://jsfiddle.net/kAt7E/47/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/kAt7E/48/).  So this is somewhat disturbing to have so many different rules.

Answer (score 8):

[Per the Mustache spec](https://github.com/mustache/spec/blob/72233f3ffda9e33915fd3022d0a9ebbcce265acd/specs/sections.yml#L27-L29), truthiness is dependent on the host language. There have been [multiple](https://github.com/mustache/spec/pull/3) [attempts](https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/28) to [standardize](https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/4) this across languages, but the consensus was that the host language had the final say.

Meaning, in JavaScript, anything for which `!!val === true` is truthy, and anything where `!!val === false` is falsey. If different Mustache implementations in the same host language inconsistently apply this spec, it's a bug in the implementation.

Comment: on http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html it also says "[If the foo key exists and has] a value of false or an empty list, the HTML between the pound and slash will not be displayed", so it seems that `!!val === false` or `val` is `[]`, then also false.

Comment: It's not that Mustache considers `[]` as falsey, per se. It's more that the section will be rendered zero times for an empty array — just like it would be rendered once for an array with one element, or 10 times for an array with 10 elements.