# How to debug Mustache js template?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache

I am using **mustache.js** to render client . I defined tempalte script and passing model object(array).
Sometimes , I am not seeing the object values in UI . How to debug this .

I am iterating the "modules" and creating a table row . There are some cases where the GUI becomes empty but the model is actually having data.
In this cases , I want to debug here . How to debug this template.

```
<script id="SomeTemplate" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
   {{#modules}}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="test">{{Name}}</td>
                        <td class="test">{{label}}</td>
                        <td class="{{XClass}}">{{Voltage}}</td>
                        <td class="{{YClass}}">{{Current}}</td>
                        <td class="{{ZClass}}">{{power}}</td>
                    </tr>
   {{/modules}}
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: i've been using tons of console.log to make sure values are really there and accurate. it doesn't debug the template directly but it's helped.

Comment: i've never seen class placeholders. that's pretty cool.

Comment: Not a solution, but it occasionally comes in handy: https://mustache.github.io/#demo

Comment: It's hard to tembug mustache templates. And starting now tembugging is a word. The best approach is the one above. Trying everything else means that you will probably end up checking your model before it's getting into the template, and that's your only chance i suppose.

Comment: "There are some cases where the GUI becomes empty but the model is actually having data": Could you post some examples of data for the failing cases? I see no alternative to debug this without knowledge about the data that fails.

Comment: Are you using handlebars or mustache ? The tags you use are a bit confusing as this are 2 differents js even if the syntax is quite the same.

Comment: If you are using handlebars you could use a helper like in this link : http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-3-tips-and-tricks

Comment: I am not using handlebars . I am using plain Mustachejs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The template you provide is quite straightforward, there is nothing obviously wrong with it. You also state that it works for some cases, which indicates that the template itself is not the problem.

From the info you provide, there is not much we can do to debug except to test that the template actually works with `Mustache.js` by rendering some dummy data that fit the template:

```js
var template = document.getElementById('SomeTemplate').innerHTML;

console.log(Mustache.render(template, {
  modules: [
    {
      'Name': 'someName',
      'label': 'someLabel',
      'XClass': 'someXClass',
      'Voltage': 'someVoltage',
      'YClass': 'someYClass',
      'Current': 'someCurrent',
      'ZClass': 'someZClass',
      'power': 'somePower'
    }
  ]
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.2.1/mustache.js"></script>
<script id="SomeTemplate" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
   {{#modules}}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="test">{{Name}}</td>
                        <td class="test">{{label}}</td>
                        <td class="{{XClass}}">{{Voltage}}</td>
                        <td class="{{YClass}}">{{Current}}</td>
                        <td class="{{ZClass}}">{{power}}</td>
                    </tr>
   {{/modules}}
</script>
```

This works fine, which tells us that the problem is elsewhere, possibly that some of the data in the actually provided `modules` array differ from what the template expects.

Thus, to debug further, I would look at some of the actual data from the cases that fail to render as expected and test those data in the console as in the script above.

Some possible guesses about what could trigger failure (only speculation, needs to be tested against actually failing cases):

- The variable names have varying capitalization, `label` is all lowercase, `Current` is firstcaps. In `Mustache.js`, case matters, so unless this is consistent in the provided data, it could cause variables not to render.
- `Mustache.js` may not render variables with `falsy` values. What is considered truthy or falsy is not always clear, see [What is truthy or falsy in Mustache and Handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444525/what-is-truthy-or-falsy-in-mustache-and-handlebars)